# Button in LinearLayout not displayed in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a `button` in `linearlayout` above the image. The image is displaying properly, but the `linearlayout` above the image is not displayed.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E9E0DB" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editdialogstartedlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.masonrytest.views.ScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profdialogphotoimageview"
            android:text="There Is Nothing Negative In Total Exploitation Of Natural Resources. What Say?"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text1"
                android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="By Andrew"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/member" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/udebate_fav" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="64"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: Fun fact its behind the image... Relative Layout allows for z-Ordering of views. You can't tell it to be above something that is matching the height and width of the parent layout...

Answer (score 2):

Try it.

remove following property from LinearLayout.

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
```

and put

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and also you need to put following property in "**com.example.masonrytest.views.ScaleImageView**"

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/editdialogstartedlayout"
```

now you get the actual View which you need.
In your old code Your Button not view because of  has fill-parent height so, it takes all size of the screen. and LinearLayout above of this layout that's why its gone above of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your root level (the RelativeLayout) has children that all have fill_parent/match_parent. This means that all items are going to fill the available space. You will only see the last one (@+id/textlayout). Think about what you are trying to achieve with your layout.

If you use Eclipse, there is also a GUI you can test with.

Comment: my problem is the image and the below linearlayout are displaying fine only the top linearlayout above the image is not displayed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E9E0DB" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/editdialogstartedlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.example.masonrytest.views.ScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editdialogstartedlayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profdialogphotoimageview"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="There Is Nothing Negative In Total Exploitation Of Natural Resources. What Say?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text1"
            android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="By Andrew"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/member" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/udebate_fav" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="64"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to main layout here  `RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main"`
 and add
 `android:layout_below="@+id/main" to  LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

in the element **com.example.masonrytest.views.ScaleImageView** try adding the following line:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/editdialogstartedlayout"
```